# It is possible for someone in the USA with a US tourist visa to visit Canada for a few days and return with a US student visa?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, tourist-visas, study

I am in the USA, I entered with a tourist visa, which allows me to stay 90 days in the country. But I also have a student visa that allows me to stay longer (studying). Is it possible to go to Canada for a few days with my US tourist visa and re-enter the USA with my US student visa?

Comment: this is so incredibly confusing. how did you end up with two valid USA visas at the same time. why you didn't enter on your student visa. how did you get 90 days when practically all entry stamps are six months. and so forth.

Comment: Do you mean you entered the US on the Visa Waiver Program instead? VWP visitors are admitted for 90 days, whereas people on B2 visitor visas are usually admitted for 6 months (though it could be shorter).

Comment: @chx the obvious conclusion is that Charly has entered under the visa waiver program but made the incredibly common mistake of calling that a "tourist visa."

Comment: Closing as unclear until citizenship and visa situation is cleared up.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a Canadian visa to visit Canada (unless you have a passport that is visa-exempt to Canada, in which case you will need an eTA if arriving in Canada by air).

When you return to the US, yes, you can enter on your US student visa if you are within 30 days of the start of your student program.